# Can't access scope variable in view

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, angularjs-scope

I'm new in Angular. I can't access the scope variable in view.

**Controller**

```
 $scope.getData = function (val) {   
      alert(val)  
      $scope.value= val;
  }
```

**view**

```
   <pre>{{value}}</pre>
```

Comment: where are you invoking the getData()?

Comment: ng-click.I got the value in alert and console.but not in view

Comment: added in my answer.. please look into and let me know is it what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

define

```
$scope.values = {thisValue:value}
```

then int html

```
{{values.thisValue}}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/robert07ravikumar/m3n450h1/

**ANGULAR CODE**

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.printName = function(name) {
       $scope.namePrint = name;
    };
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="well" ng-controller="MyController">

    <button ng-click="printName('robert ravikumar')">print name</button>

    <span>{{namePrint}}</span>
    </div>
```

The assign the value to the scope variable(namePrint) and use scope variable double brackets to show it in view

Answer (score -1):

The same code works **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/wm8u9sdc/)**

You can use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive to bind html data.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <pre ng-bind-html-unsafe="value"></pre>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/meybbron/1/)**

Comment: i cant access team viewer.in many places i used scope variable.

Comment: In my view page i checked on condition using ng-if.(value =1)that result in <pre>{{value}}</pre> is 1

Comment: change it as value==1

Comment: hi u there..i need ur help

Comment: soryy..u there now..i'm in chat link

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"> <input type="button"  value="GetData " ng-click="GetData('myNewValueProvidedFromHtml')" /></div>

    </div>


  <span ng-bind="value"></span>
</div>
```

Angular

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.value = "my value";

    $scope.GetData = function (newValue) {
        $scope.value = newValue;

    }


});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `$scope.$digest()` to tell angular to reprocess the view.  ie:

```
$scope.getData = function (val) {   
  alert(val)  
  $scope.value= val;
  $scope.$digest();
}
```